# Manipulate JSON using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON which I need to manipulate using Javascript or JQuery, this is how the structure looks at the moment.

```
{
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I only need the bit between square brackets.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to strip out the bits inside the square brackets, including the brackets themselves?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you know how to parse JSON in JavaScript? Do you know how to get the property of an object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var my_json = '{"phoneNumbers":[{"type":"home","number":"212 555-1234"},{"type":"fax","number":"646 555-4567"}]}';
var my_object = JSON.parse(my_json);
var the_thing_i_care_about = my_object.phoneNumbers
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a string from server response or whatever, in JavaScript, first you need to parse a JSON string to JSON object. Use $.parseJSON(your JSON string) if you use jQuery, and also can use JSON.parse(your JSON string) in pure JavaScript,modern browser like Chrome,Firefox,etc support this API.

Then manipulate JSON object is dead easy. For example:

```
var phoneNumbers = $.parseJSON(your JSON string);
console.log(phoneNumbers[0].type);// get the first number type
phoneNumbers[0].type = "new type";// update the first number type "home" to "new type"
```

The end, i guess you'll need parse the JSON object to string to post to server.

```
var phoneNumbersJSONString = JSON.stringify(phoneNumbers); // pure JavaScript API;
```

to support all browsers, check this [json library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Dead easy,right?